# Error Selecting element by XPATH_Selector in Colab

Tags: selenium, web, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I have a problem when I use selenium in google Colab
this problem appears when I use the XPATH selector in my code, my script is running right well in the local machine, but in google Colab, it doesn't work.

that is the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H9pO.png)

```
List item

ib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:37: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_ "commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead".
```

Also when I replace `XPATH_selector` with `find_element_by_` always the problem is stilling.

Comment: Please share your code and HTML